# ViewController not refreshing when app launches if view is last one open

Tags: ios, uitableview, apple-push-notifications

Apologies for the weird headline, can't think of a better way to describe it.

I'm building my app and have managed to get push notifications to work (Yay!).
If I send a push notification to the phone and tap the notification the function `didReceiveRemoteNotification:` in `AppDelegate` gets called and works as expected.

If I ignore the notification and load the app as per normally, the `UITableView` page doesn't refresh and I have to move off the view and then back to get `viewDidAppear` to refresh the view.

How do I get the app / view to refresh the page when the user navigates back to the app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to get the `tableView` to reloadData from `applicationDidBecomeActive` or post a notification to reload your tableview from this method like below?

```
func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {
     yourVC.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: Bingo! That was what I was looking for. Thank you